# elpy with ipython as rpc -- how to get good autocompletion

Tags: auto-complete-mode, ipython, elpy

I'm using elpy with emacs and python3.  Here's the relevant part of my .emacs:

```
;; PYTHON
(elpy-enable)
(setq elpy-rpc-python-command "python3")
(elpy-use-ipython "ipython3")
(autoload 'jedi:setup "jedi" nil t)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(add-hook 'pyvenv-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(setq jedi:setup-keys t)
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)
```

Now, if I create a class in a python file, auto completion works perfectly.  Then I try C-c C-c, and the class is loaded up in my ipython buffer, and I can play around with it.  So far so good.

Unfortunatly, this is where I really want auto-complete, but my autocomplete experience here is a little unsatisfactory.  Out of the box I can use tab to get completions in another window, but I'd like the "on dot popup" I get in python mode.   Executuing `jedi:setup` gives me popups, but it's just builtins, and not my class methods.

How can I get the same auto complete behavior in my ipython rpc buffer as I get in my python editing buffer?

Answer (score 3):

Elpy doesn't require emacs jedi package. Also they won't work well when both are configured. I guess there is some conflict between them.

Use only elpy and you should be able to get completion in rpc buffer.

I created an empty file with

```
class Foo:
    this = 2
```

After sending this to python buffer with <kbd>C-C C-c</kbd>, if i switch to python buffer and type `Foo.` it gives completions.

[image]

Comment: The claim that they won't work well together seems to contradict what [elpy's own FAQ has to say](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/wiki/FAQ#q-should-i-use-rope-or-jedi) on the matter!

Comment: FAQ is talking about Python Jedi. Here we are discussing emacs jedi?

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. Sorry about the noise.

Comment: What is your configuration for this to work? I'm in the same situation as the OP, it is not really working for me by default.

Comment: @Daniel My elpy config https://github.com/ChillarAnand/eddie/blob/master/ubuntu/config/emacs/init.el#L417-L428

Comment: Thanks! But I actually made it work yesterday. Turns out I had to downgrade ipython.